# Double port forwarding - modem and router

Tags: router, port-forwarding, port, modem

I am created a small home server with centos. I needed to acess the server over internet.

I have one router and one modem. The router is wireless wifi router.It have a web interface. I can port forward to the specific server ip on the LAN with the help of router. But the internet accessed by modem. The modem connected to the router.The one of the major problem is modem have no web interface.

i am planned modem to router DMZ configuration - but there is no web interface available in the modem. How can port forward from modem to router?

Comment: If the modem is a modem it doesn’t need to be set up. What external IP does your “router” show?

Comment: external ip of the modem and the router external ip are different.means that, the web interface of router shows one ip address.  when i checked my ip on google it will show different ip.

Comment: Unfortunately, considering the possibility of carrier-grade NAT, that doesn’t mean anything. What type of access do you have? ADSL/VDSL? Cable? Some sort of mobile network? What’s your ISP? // Almost forgot: Please perform a traceroute to Google (or whatever) and include the output in your question. Please note that your public IP will never appear in the output so please keep censoring to a minimum.

Comment: How is the router configured to access it's WAN interface?  If it is something like PPPoE you might effectively be NATed, or otherwise locked in a private IP address space.  That could make problems that could only be solved via a tunnel or VPN.  Can you give the first couple of bytes of your router's external IP address?

Comment: i am using Railwire internet. modem is optical.@DanielB

Comment: i m using PPPoE connection.@infixed

Comment: That basically means you are inside your ISP's private network, and you can think of yourself being inside a NATed network you don't control.  So if you want to listen outside that NAT, you need a VPN (or a VPS set up as a VPN) or a tunnel.  If your outside access supports IPV6 and your router has IPv6rd support, its not too difficult to use Hurricane Electrics loss-leader 'free' tunnels to get a routable IPv6 address

Comment: if i contact with the isp provider here, is he able to forward the port?

Comment: I don't know. It's technically possible.  But I would not be surprised if they try to get you to pay to upgrade you to a business-level account with a fixed IP address if you do.

Comment: K. Thanks  For the Valuable information. @infixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re connecting to the modem via PPPoE, it really works like a modem. That means you already get all the data your ISP sends you, unfiltered.

(Theoretically, it could still filter the traffic, but that’s unlikely.)

Coupled with the fact that your “real” public IP address is different from the one your router shows means you’re behind a [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) system. Seeing how you’re from India, there’s probably a severe shortage of IPv4 addresses, making things like that necessary.

Your ISP will not set up a port forwarding for you. It’s most likely impossible for them, even if they wanted to.

Like @infixed speculated, they will direct to a business plan. These plans usually include fixed IP addresses (among other things) but are a lot more expensive.

You could get a cheap Virtual Private Server, set up a VPN server on it and connect to this VPN server both from your home server and mobile clients. That way, you would be able to access your home server (and with proper setup the entire home network).